# Performance different between various request methods in Laravel

Tags: laravel

on laravel, there is a specific class named Illuminate\Http\Request which provided an object-oriented way to interact with HTTP request which are send by client-side

it can be accessed by two methods as follows,

```
$name = $request->input('name');
$name = $request->name;
```

which one is the most efficient way to get the request?

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: You'll **never** notice a difference. Just stick to one syntax for consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one with input() is the mainly documented way of doing it, so I'd recommend using it as the functionnality is quite well established and the behavior is quite known.

The second one is a syntaxic sugar that map unexisting properties to inputs. It may be more concise however it uses a magic method call that will be potentially slower (check that a property exist, recognise it doesn't, resolve the magic call and execute the magic call).

However, while the performance difference is quite negligible for most usages, I'll not recommend using the second method anyway.

In fact, as the Request class semantics may change in future versions, you have no guarantee that a property will not be created with the same name as an input used in your application. This may or may not create bugs when upgrading the framework down the line as all your code will now be referencing this new property instead of the inputed value as you intend it to.

Answer (score -4):

Those methods aren't the only ones in Laravel
but the method

```
$name = $request->input('name');
```

you must be aware that using unvalidated data directly in your controller is also considered a security vuln.
You should use this instead, as it is suggested by the Laravel creators.

```php
public function store(Request $request){
  $request->validate([
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:0', 'max:255'],
  ]);

  $name = $request->get('name', 'Something here so if its not defined you can handle it, but will more likely be defined, because in the validate method we have required for this field :), but just should you know, it can also be null or empty');
}
```

Your second suggestions is called magic properties in laravel, and yeah you can do it too, but remember you should ALWAYS validate your request data first before using it, you cannot possibly trust your users after all.

Comment: *have been deprecated due to security issues* - where are you getting this? [The docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input) mention nothing about this.

Comment: In fact `input` is a wrapper around `get` which I believe is a symphony method.

Comment: yeah your right, my bad sorry, edited my comment tho ;)

Comment: *You should use this instead, as it is suggested by the Laravel creators* - once again, where are you getting this from?

Comment: I agree that input should be validated, but SQL injection attacks are mostly mitigated by the Eloquent ORM, and have nothing to do with the performance question the OP is asking about.

Comment: About Laravel creators suggestions, i talked about the validation not the get method.

Comment: Even so, how does it answer the question - *which one is the most efficient way to get the request*?

Comment: what you have here as a code example is actually a problem in itself, you may not be validating the input you are actually trying to access there ... https://asklagbox.com/blog/illuminate-request#you-dont-get-it